# How to setup the structure of org mode with a known html file?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, html

I want to create an Org file, then export to HTML such that the final site looks something like this: https://html5up.net/dimension. If you go to their `index.html` file, their structure in HTML looks like this:

```
 <html>
    <head>
     .......
    </head>
   <body>
   ........
   </body>
   <footer>
   .........
   </footer
</html>
```

Between the `<head>` and `</head>`, we have include informations like CSS file, language...etc. In my Org file, I put this at the top:

```
#+TITLE: My website
#+AUTHOR: My name
#+HTML_HEAD: <title>Tab title for website</title>
#+HTML_HEAD:  <meta charset="utf-8" />
#+HTML_HEAD: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
#+HTML_HEAD: <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript>
```

When I export the Org file with the above to HTML, the HTML's source code matches the `<head>...</head>` portion in the original `index.html` from their site. So this is OK.

The problem is in the `<body>...</body>`. There are nested `div`, `class`, `span`...etc, each with special id/class name. For example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <header id="header">
       <div class="logo">
          <span class="icon fa-gem"></span>
       </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

How do I achieve this structure and able to customize the name (div,header,span....) and the special id (wrapper,header,logo...)? Some org-babel?

I tried to do:

```
* first
** second
*** third
```

to see how this translates to HTML, the result is:

```
<li><a href="#org130eef2">1. first</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#org16f1ab9">1.1. second</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#org3aa5a1a">1.1.1. third</a></li>
```

which is not even close to what the structure I want.

Any help is greatly appreciated. The reason I want to go with Org mode is because it can fold stuff, so when my site gets large, I can fold/unfold header. Plus, Org works well with LaTex.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I'm pretty sure the <footer> element has to be within the <body> element.

Comment: What you are showing above is the table of contents for the document. There is more stuff generated for the body: look for a `div` with `id=outline-containter-<mumble>` and then `<h2>`, `<h3>` and `<h4>` headers.